# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type instance)

Tags: tkinter

I keep getting this really strange error that I cannot solve looking at any other post. I'm applying a background image to a tkinter canvas.

```
import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.X
import Image

root = tk.Tk(); 
background = "background.png"

photo = tk.PhotoImage(Image.open(background))
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=photo)

root.mainloop()
```

But because of the last line, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=photo)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2279, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2270, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type instance)
```

Comment: If you make your code into a complete minimal example by replacing `#...some code` with `root = tk.Tk(); background = xyz.jgp`, do you get the same exception?  (In other words, eliminate the possibility that 'some code' has a negative side-effect on the gui system.)  The line displayed is the 3rd of a 3-line return statement.  I do not see why __str__ is being called.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Yep, same error. I edited my question. There is a working version of my reduced program now.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Looks like I answered my own questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like I answered my own question. First of all, I wrote the syntactically incorrect statements:

```
background = "background.png"
photo = tk.PhotoImage(Image.open(background))
```

This should be written correctly:

```
background = "background.png"
photo = tk.PhotoImage(background)
```

Second, Tkinter does not support .png files. The correct class is ImageTk from module PIL.

```
from PIL import ImageTk as itk
background = "background.png"
photo = itk.PhotoImage(file = background)
```

And notice the difference in syntax:

```
photo = tk.PhotoImage(background)
photo = itk.PhotoImage(file = background)
```

Comment: Tkinter supports whatever image formats tcl/tk does.  Tcl/tk 8.6 supports .png.  The 3.4 Windows installer installs 8.6.1.  With 2.7, you are stuck with 8.5.x.

Comment: So is this what people mean when they say "tkinter is a wrapper class of tcl and tk?"

Comment: Yes.  Anyone interested in details can read tkinter/__init__.py (3.x) and possibly _tkinter.c.  For the most part, they translate python argment objects to tcl strings. call tcl/tk, and translate tcl return strings to python objects.

Answer (score 1):

*In additional to [the_prole's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27187107/2039993)*

Regarding to [PIL reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pil/image-tk.html)

> Warning
>
> There is a bug in the current version of the Python Imaging Library
>   that can cause your images not to display properly. When you create an
>   object of class PhotoImage, the reference count for that object does
>   not get properly incremented, so unless you keep a reference to that
>   object somewhere else, the PhotoImage object may be garbage-collected,
>   leaving your graphic blank on the application.
>
> For example, if you have a canvas or label widget that refers to such
>   an image object, keep a list named .imageList in that object, and
>   append all PhotoImage objects to it as they are created. If your
>   widget may cycle through a large number of images, you will also want
>   to delete the objects from this list when they are no longer in use.

Your code will be as below

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk as itk

root = tk.Tk(); 
background = 'background.png'

photo = itk.PhotoImage(file= background)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.imageList = []
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=photo)
canvas.imageList.append(photo)

root.mainloop()
```

Also, about transparent PNG:
For example in Photoshop, when you save a picture as PNG, PNG options also can cause your images not to display properly.